# Rename with regex characters, bash

Tags: regex, bash, rename

I've a (basic) problem renaming some files using regex expressions but none of solutions I've found seem to work... any could help me to identify the error or suggest another (correct) solution? Thanks!

These are my files:

```
378_MO_1_S17_R1.fastq.gz
378_MO_1_S17_R2.fastq.gz
378_MO_2_S2_R1.fastq.gz
378_MO_2_S2_R2.fastq.gz
```

And I want to rename them to this...

```
378_MO_1_r323_R1.fastq.gz
378_MO_1_r323_R2.fastq.gz
378_MO_2_r323_R1.fastq.gz
378_MO_2_r323_R2.fastq.gz
```

...using this command:

`rename 's/_S[0-9]{1,}_/_r323_/g' *.gz`

Comment: your command would work if you have the perl based rename command.. check `man rename` to see what version of rename you have.. there are multiple implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop and parameter expansions:

```
for fname in *.gz; do
  echo mv -- "$fname" "${fname%%_S*}_r323_${fname##*_}"
done
```

If its output looks good, remove `echo`.